# Shinydashboard: Cannot link css file in dashboard body

Tags: css, shinydashboard

I have the following app folder structure:

```
projectFolder
  |
  -- 00_Data
  -- 01_Shiny
       |
       -- ui.R
       -- server.R
       -- www
           |
           -- custom.css
  -- 02_Misc
  -- project.rproj
```

In the `ui.R` file I have:

```
body <- dashboardBody(
  
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
  ),
...
)
```

The css file is not applied and I don't understand why. It works if I use

```
body <- dashboardBody(

  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

      body {
        background-color: white;
        color: black; /* text color */
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
      }
    ")))
    ...
)
```

But I would like to avoid this and load the css from an external file. Can someone pinpoint to what I'm missing?

Comment: Try `includeCSS("www/custom.css")` in your `ui`

Comment: Thanks, that worked, though I had to supply an absolute path.